# How do I get the client name from a socket in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

Sorry, simple question...but I can't find the answer anywhere using google or in textbooks! I have a simple server, to which a user connects via a socket in java. I want to use this Java socket to retrieve the users client name, is this possible ?

I know I can use the getInetAddress() method to returns the address to which the socket is connected, but that isn't really what I want. Is there any easy way of doing this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
getInetAddress().getHostName()
```

[Reference Link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName%28%29)

EDIT: is your code structured like this?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
public class Test {
    public void foo() throws IOException{

            ServerSocket server = null; //Initialize server socket here.

            Socket client = server.accept();
            String hostName = client.getInetAddress().getHostName();
        }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting a cannot find method error on getInetAddress while trying to run this, even though I have import java.net.*;
 and import java.io.*; in my code. Any ideas ?

Comment: I won't even say what I was doing it was so embarrassingly silly, got there in the end though...thank you very much for the response!