# Socket programming client name

Tags: java

Is there any way to get client name at the server side before "accepting" the connection? Using java.

I am new to java.

thanks in advance..

Comment: I believe that you have to accept first, but you can close the connection from the server any time. So accept, get your client information, and keep open or close as your application logic dictates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the client name from a socket in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112325/how-do-i-get-the-client-name-from-a-socket-in-java)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels., my logic of program is.... the client get message when the server accepts the request., but in the server i actually want to verify the "client name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get client name at the server side before "accepting" the connection?

No - you must accept the connection first. Then you may read the host's name and choose the next course of action.

```
Socket client = server.accept();
String hostName = client.getInetAddress().getHostName();
```

Answer (score 0):

The client name (the client hostname) is avalaible only from the Socket client, so you need to accept it first and then then to react accordingly.

```
private static final String ALLOWED_NAME = "my.hostname.com";

....

Socket client = server.accept();
String hostName = client.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName();

if(hostName.equalsIgnoreCase(ALLOWED_NAME)
{
   // DO NOTHING
}
else 
{
   client.close();
}
```

Reference:

- [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)
- [InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)

Please be sure to get the difference between [getCanonicalHostname](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName%28%29)() and [getHostname()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName%28%29).